HTML images will not up and downscale properly
I have the following HTML code (simplified)
<div class="media-bar">
    <div class="media-viewer">
        <div class="action-bar">

        </div>
        <div class="media-socket">
            <button></button>
            <div class="input-socket">
                <img class="input-socket-item">
                <video class="input-socket-item"></video>
            </div>
            <button></button>
        </div>
        <div class="media-selector">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

and this CSS code:
.media-bar {
    height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
}

.media-viewer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

.media-socket {
    min-height: 300px; /* Temp */
    display: flex;
    flex: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-socket {
    justify-content: center;
}

.input-socket-item {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

However, no matter what I try, I cannot get that .input-socket-item to scale how I'd like (or, to be honest, at all unless I manually set the height!). I'd like it so it scales to fit the .input-socket. The height of the image won't scale down properly, so the image is getting cut off. If I switch the width and height fields, the same problem persists, but just with the width instead. Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated, because I cannot figure this out.

Could you turn this into a snippet and add a placeholder image so we can see what you mean? Because just from the code it seems it should work. You can use the <> button to add HTML, CSS and JS for inclusion, and you can use something like placehold.it for your image (like https://placehold.it/200x200). This would make it miles easier for us to help you. (Please also change the placehold.it width and height to something matching your image)

@somethinghere i tried suggesting an edit with the code snippet but the code is simplified to the point where it will not even show anything. it just shows 2 symmetrical empty buttons.

When using Flexbox instead of working with width and height to set your Element properties, try using flex-shrink and flex-grow.
Here I have told your code to shrink the image to fit the size of the flexbox. and your buttons to grow to fill the remaining space to keep the image and video item center. I have also changed .media-bar to be of the flex-row type. I also hope I understood your question correctly. I'm not super sure if you want to adjust it or also make it responsive. To make this design responsive the parent element is important.
    .media-bar {
        display: flex;
    }

    .media-viewer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .media-socket {
        display: flex;
        height: 300px;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .input-socket {
        height: 100%;
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }

    .input-socket-item {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .flex-button {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

        <div class="media-bar">
            <div class="media-viewer">
                <div class="action-bar">
                    actionbar
                </div>
                <div class="media-socket">
                    <div class="flex-button">
                        <button>Previous</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-socket">
                        <img class="input-socket-item" src="null">
                        <video class="input-socket-item"></video>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-button">
                        <button>Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media-selector">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

